# Low quality image in TabPage header using TabControl ImageList

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabpage

I'm having a problem with the image quality of the image that is displayed on the TabPage header.  My source image is a 16x16 png with transparency.  When I load it into the TabPage header, the quality is horrible.  So far, the best I've been able to come up with is to use an 8 bit png instead of a 32 bit png.  This helps significantly, but the quality is still not as good as I would like, and still not as good as a 32 bit png.  Does anyone have a good method of preserving the png quality?

(32 bit original on left. 32 bit tab header lower quality on right.)

[image]

(8 bit original on left. 8 bit tab header lower quality on right.)

[image]

(32 bit original on left. 8 bit tab header lower quality on right.)

[image]

I'm trying/hoping to get it as close as possible to looking like the original 32 bit png.

I'm using the below code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1
{
    public void Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // initialize the imagelist
        ImageList imageList1 = new ImageList();
        imageList1.Images.Add("key1", Properties.Resources.Image1png);
        imageList1.Images.Add("key2", Properties.Resources.Image2png);

        //initialize the tab control
        TabControl tabControl1 = new TabControl();
        tabControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tabControl1.ImageList = imageList1;
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add("tabKey1", "TabText1", "key1"); 
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add("tabKey2", "TabText2", "key2");
        this.Controls.Add(tabControl1);
    }
}
```

Comment: snapshot please and let's see what is horrible you are talking about.

Comment: @David - I added links to images above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this answers your question, but have to post it as answer to include the snapshot.

You might try below:

1. Select the image list;
2. Config the ColorDepth property, and set it from "Depth8bit" to "Depth32bit"

[image]

Or simply change it in code:

```
imageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  It's late here and my eyes are burning, and at the moment everything looks blurry. :)  I will evaluate it more carefully in the morning when my eyes are fresh, and then I will report back to let you know.

Comment: No, the quality definitely degrades. :)  I have been experimenting with it for the past 10 minutes, and at the moment I think the best combination is when I use the 8 bit image but set the color depth to 32 bit.  Using 32 bit image with 32 bit color depth still modifies the image significantly, even if better than when color depth was set to 8 bit.  Tomorrow I will do more tests and post more images to this thread.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I still find this all a bit strange.  It seems that the best I can get is using the 8bit image and then setting the color depth to 32 bit on the image list.  I'm going to mark this as an answer because it will suffice, even though I still am not able to get the original 32 bit image quality to appear on the tab header.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the ImageList (associated to TabControl), remove all images and add them again in the same order.

That's the only way it works for me!